# How to reciprocate fseek(fp, -1) in python

Tags: python, c

Hi guys how do i reciprocate

```
fseek(fp, -1)
```

in python.
Thus after doing `fileObject.read(2)`
i will like to send the read head one step back

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
fileObject.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)
```

More information on the `seek` method can be found [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek).